# double sided polygons in BGE

Tags: game-engine, materials, objects, shaders

Is there a way to render both sides of a polygon in the game engine? Because as far as I know polygons have "normals" which means that the side with the normal is what will be shaded on the polygon, and games usually have two sides
Grass for example will be visible from both sides of the polygon that it is mapped to. Is Blender capable of something like that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a check box in the material settings tab of the properties window, called *"Backface Culling"*.  Simply uncheck that box and your object will render both sides of the faces in the game engine.
[image: Backface Culling setting]

Comment: Oh I was confusing that with the other one in the shading options. Thanks :)